# Program error and questions regarding max. log-likelihood

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the maximum log-likelihood (MLE) for the following probability density function (PDF):

[image: pdf]

I'm computing it by minimising the objective function (negative log-likelihood) without relying on any predefined log-likelihood python built-in modules whatsoever. The code is:

```
# Alpha Distribution (PDF)
def AD(z, *params): 
    a, scale = z
    diameters = params
    return -np.sum(np.log((((diameters)/(a**2) * np.exp(-diameters/a))) / scale))

# load data
currpath = ('path')
os.chdir(currpath)
diameters = scipy.io.loadmat('data.mat')["m1"]

# minimise
x0 = [1,1] # initial guesses
res = optimize.minimize(AD, x0, args = diameters, method='Nelder-Mead', 
                    tol=1e-6)
print(res.x)
```

My data vector (here already sorted) comprises a number of diameters in the following form (0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.25, 0.27 ...).

**First question: Since I'm fairly new to the topic of MLE, is the form of my data vector correct?** I'm not completely sure whether I use a data vector containing every observed diameter (like shown above), or a data vector which only contains the "possible" diameters (which would be: 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22, 0.25, 0.27 ...), or just the frequencies of the observed diameters (which would be: 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1 ...). I think the first option is the right one, but I just wanted to be completely sure.

**Second question: If I wish to use a cumulative distribution function (CDF) instead of a PDF to perform my MLE on, I would have to change my PDF function to a CDF, right?** I was just wondering if I could alternatively somehow modify my data vector and still use the PDF.

However, for the minimisation in python (if I understood it correctly) I had to rethink the definition of my variables. That means, normally I would assume that the parameters of my PDF (here "a" and "scale") are the variables which should be passed to "args" in "optimize.minimize". However, in the documentation it is stated, that args should contain the "constant" parameters, therefore I used my data vector as a constant "parameter vector" for the minimisation.

**Third question: Is this assumption an error in reasoning?**

**Fourth question: Is the optimisation method "Nelder-Mead" appropriate?** I'm not really familiar with optimisation methods and not sure which of the options I should use/is the best.

Finally, the program returns an error *"TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'"*, where I have no clue how to deal with it, since I'm not passing any tuples to the minimisation function ...

**Fifth question: Where does the tuple come from and how can I solve this error?**

I'd appreciate any help you could give me very much!

Best regards!

PS: Since this post is kind of a mixture between general math and programming, I wasn't completely sure if this is the right place to put the question. Sorry if I'm mistaken!

Comment: Before I attempt your questions, can you please give us the formula for that density function in its primitive state, that is, before you turned it into a log-likelihood function. It would be nicer if your could insert that into your question as a mathematics graphic if possible.

Comment: @BillBell Added the formula. It seems, that I can't yet add images directly to my post, therefore its a link.

Comment: @BillBell Also, since I'm computing it numerically, I don't actually "transform" the PDF into a log-likelihood function (by changing the whole formula). This means, I just calculate the logarithms for every diameter of my PDF, add them together and multiply this with -1 (in order to search the minimum) -> (-np.sum(np.log((((diameters)/(a**2) * np.exp(-diameters/a))) / scale))). Hope that's not already wrong?

Comment: Can you post your complete sample of diameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, apart from the first part (before the multiplication operator), we are discussing what is generally called maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) for the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). It has just been reparameterised in terms of something called *a*.

We want to estimate this **single** parameter based on a sample of diameters; there is no scale parameter. Under MLE, we pretend that the sample is fixed and treat the parameter as something that can be varied. We form the *likelihood* of the sample by taking the product of the density functions (*not* the cdfs) where each density function is to be calculated for one element of the sample.

(Likelihood is, in concept, like throwing a die twice. In ultra ugly terms, we could say that the likelihood of getting two ones in a row might be (1/6)(1/6).)

We want to maximise this likelihood. However, to make the optimisation problem mathematically and/or computationally tractable we take the function's logarithm. Since all of its constituent functions are densities, less than one, this function must be everywhere less than zero. Thus, the maximisation problem becomes one of minimisatiion.

If you want to avoid almost all of the algebra then you would:

- Write a function to calculate the density function for a given diameter and parameter value.
- Write another function that would accept a density function parameter value as its Python parameter, and the sample as its second. Make it call the first function once for each sample value, take the log of each of these and return the sum of these.
- Call `minimize` with the second function as its first argument, some reasonable guess for the density function parameter, in a list, as the second argument, the sample for `args`. Nelder-Mead is probably ok.

**Edit: In a nutshell:**

```
diameters =[ 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.25, 0.27]

from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import exp, log

def pdf(d, a):
    result = d*exp(-d/a)/a**2
    return result

def log_L(a, diameters):
    result = sum(log(pdf(d, a)) for d in diameters)
    return result

res = minimize(log_L, [1], args=diameters)

print (res)
```

Output:

```
      fun: -337.80985348524604
 hess_inv: array([[  8.71770021e+10]])
      jac: array([ -7.62939453e-06])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 93
      nit: 30
     njev: 31
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 2157576.39996697])
```

---

Addendum:

The wikipedia article offers the following form for the pdf of the exponential.

[image: exponential]

The constant 'lambda' can be viewed as a value that scales the integral of the remainder of the expression from zero to infinity to one. We can ignore it and equate the exponents of your pdf, without the scaling factor, and the exponential. We have to remember that `d` takes the role of `x`.

[image: equation]

Solve for 'lambda'.

[image: expression for lambda]

We see that this is the normalising expression in your pdf. In other words, the alpha is an exponential expressed with different parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The function I'm using should be/is an alpha distribution. I also looked up your link of the exponential function to check it, and there the variable "diameter" in front of the exponent is missing. So I don't think they're the same. I added the "scale" parameter to the pdf by myself, because my first attempt was to use the least-square algorithm to fit my PDF to my data. Naturally one want to fit the amplitude as well, therefore I included this additional parameter to do exactly that (although "a" is kind of doing that too, but not explicitly).

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your following statement. If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you're saying that each element of my sample vector forms an own density function as soon as I give them to my PDF. But shouldn't they just form one value/realisation of the underlying density function I'm working with (my alpha distribution)?

Comment: My function AD(z, *params) should be doing the steps 1 and 2 you proposed in your post at once. Instead of calling a function sequentially, where just one value of the PDF for one diameter is calculated, I'm doing it all at once by using the whole sample vector as an input to my computations. So I generate an array with my PDF results for all diameters, take the logarithm of this array (and therefore of every element of my density function/PDF) and sum up the result. But I will try your sequential approach and will see if I can avoid that "tuple" error.

Comment: Please see addendum concerning how 'alpha' is an exponential.

Comment: You're 2nd comment: In MLE this is *always* true. You form the product of the densities **given** the individual sample values and then you maximise this product over the space of parameter values. But in practice, we usually do the mathematics of finding the product mathematically, then of calculating its log-likelihood because this becomes a tractable optimisation problem. However, as I said, if you don't want to do the mathematics you don't need to.

Comment: It's nonsense because I forgot to negate the log-likelihood!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, assuming that you're analysing data and not simply working out the details of MLE.

scipy provides means for generating samples from arbitrary distributions. Here I define just the pdf for your alpha. Your parameter `a` becomes `p` because `a` is used as the lower limit for the distribution support, which I define to be zero.

I draw a sample of size 100 with `p` set somewhat arbitrarily to 0.4. I did a little experimentation, trying to find a value that would give me a sample whose lowest 11 values would approximate those in your sample.

The scipy rv_continuous object has a method called `fit` that will attempt calculation of MLE estimates of location, scale and 'shape'. In this case, the value for shape, about 0.36, is not all that far from 0.4.

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import numpy as np

class Alpha(rv_continuous):
    'alpha distribution'
    def _pdf(self, x, p):
        return x*np.exp(-x/p)/p**2

alpha = Alpha(a=0, shapes='p')
sample = sorted(alpha.rvs(size=100,p=0.4))
for a in sample[:12]:
    print ('{:10.2f}'.format(a))

print (Alpha(a=0, shapes='p').fit(sample))
```

I don't believe that your sample is alpha-distributed. The values seem to be too 'uniform' compared with what I could generate. But I've been wrong before.

I would suggest plotting your sample cdf to see if you can recognise what it is.

Incidentally, when I changed the sign of the log-likelihood in the other answer the code croaked. I **suspect** that the alpha is just a poor fit.

```
      0.00
      0.03
      0.04
      0.04
      0.08
      0.09
      0.09
      0.11
      0.12
      0.14
      0.19
      0.20
(1.0902616847853124, -0.039102949269294023, 0.35922022997329517)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answers! I still have one question about the transformation from the exponential PDF into the alpha PDF (see your first answer). When I solve the equation -lambda*d = -d/a for 'lambda', I get 1/a and not d/a^2 ... Am I missing something?

Comment: Regarding your second answer. I'm analysing data comprising 1480 elements. The values I have given were just an example and do not represent the actual data. So I guess that was a little bit misleading on my part, sorry! However, I will use your approach and will see if it returns realistic results when I use real data.

Comment: No worries. Best of luck, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: So, I have tested your Code from your first answer with my data (and with the added negation in front of the sum) and I think that's the right value! To confirm it, I have additionally calculated the max. log-likelihood analytically (that's one of the reasons I chose this PDF) and the results are virtually the same. So once again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. Every once in a while, something will work. ;)

Comment: I put another question in the edit of my post. If you could spare the time and look at it, this would be awesome!

Comment: I hate to say it but you should post this as a new question. Unfortunately though, it's really a completely statistical question in my opinion and most people on SO might object to its being posted here. My advice is that you put it on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.